# Read file from current path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system

I had to write a custom function to load a yaml file from the current working directory. The function itself works and my intention was to write it in a pure fashion but my senior colleague told me that the way I wrote this function is utterly bad and I have to rewrite it.

Which commandment in Python did I violate? Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here and how a "professional" solution would look like?

```
from typing import Dict
import yaml
from yaml import SafeLoader
from pathlib import Path
import os


def read_yaml_from_cwd(file: str) -> Dict:

    """[reads a yaml file from current working directory]
    Parameters
    ----------
    file : str
        [.yaml or .yml file]
    Returns
    -------
    Dict
        [Dictionary]
    """
    path = os.path.join(Path.cwd().resolve(), file)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            content = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            return content
    else:
        return None

content = read_yaml_from_cwd("test.yaml")
print(content)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which commandment did you violate?  Using `os.path` and `pathlib` in the same breath!  `pathlib` is an object-oriented replacement to `os.path`.

```
    path = os.path.join(Path.cwd().resolve(), file)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path) as f:
```

could be written as:

```
    path = Path.cwd().joinpath(file)
    if path.is_file():
        with path.open() as f:
```

or since you're starting at the current directory, simply:

```
    path = Path(file)
    if path.is_file():
        with path.open() as f:
```

Comment: I am using `ruamel yaml` in my own project, so I might be missremembering the details. I thought one could simply do `content = yaml.load(path, Loader=SafeLoader)` directly on the path without having to explicitly open it?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar That may be true; I haven't used `yaml` at all.  My answer focused on the mashup between `os.path` and `pathlib`, stopping just before the `yaml.load(...)` line for that very reason.

Comment: thank you, very helpful!